# How to use multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I have this code:

```
import thread

def print_out(m1, m2):
    print m1
    print m2
    print "\n"

for num in range(0, 10):
    thread.start_new_thread(print_out, ('a', 'b'))
```

I want to create 10 threads, each thread runs the function `print_out`, but I failed. The errors are as follows:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, you should use the higher level `threading` module and specifically the `Thread` class. The `thread` module is not what you need.

As you extend this code, you most likely will also want to wait for the threads to finish. Following is a demonstration of how to use the `join` method to achieve that:

```
import threading

class print_out(threading.Thread):

    def __init__ (self, m1, m2):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.m1 = m1
        self.m2 = m2

    def run(self):
        print self.m1
        print self.m2
        print "\n"

threads = []
for num in range(0, 10):
    thread = print_out('a', 'b')
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Comment: `thread.join()` is used to wait until the thread terminates. and i noticed that if i dont add the last two line of code: `for thread in threads: thread.join()`, the program also runs well, and every thread is executed at `thread.start()` according to debug, IOW if i dont add `time.time(0.1)`, i neednt add the code `thread.join()` because the program will automatically wait the thread to finish its task at `thread.start()`, right?

Comment: @Mark You don't need to add `time.sleep(0.1)` at all. That's just not necessary. Yes you can remove the code that calls `join` and the Python environment will wait for all threads to complete before terminating execution. However, I added the calls to `join` because I expect that you will need, at some point in the future, to know how to wait for a thread to complete its execution. But yes, you can simply omit those calls to `join` in this simple example.

Answer (score 2):

You should let the main thread stay alive for a little while. If the main thread dies, so will all the other threads and hence you will not see any output. Try adding a `time.sleep(0.1)` at the end of the code and then you will see the output.

After that, you can have a look at the `thread.join()` to get more idea about this.

Answer (score 2):

The other approach is using threading class.

```
 instance[num]=threading.Thread(target=print_out, args=('a', 'b'))

 instance[num].start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using thread module, you need to have a main thread running, by adding a while loop below

```
import thread

def print_out(m1, m2):
    print m1
    print m2
    print "\n"

for num in range(0, 10):
    thread.start_new_thread(print_out, ('a', 'b'))`

while(1):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are creating thread you need to run main thread before that.
Here you are not running any main tread.

To solve the problem you can add a print statement of any other statement.
Lets modify your code

```
import thread
import time

def print_out(m1, m2):
    print m1
    print m2
    print "\n"

for num in range(0, 10):
    thread.start_new_thread(print_out, ('a', 'b'))
    time.sleep(.1)
```

Here time.sleep() is creating main tread for you and thread.start_new_thread  creating 10 threads on the main tread.
Note: You can add any statement in place of time.sleep()