# Simple way to run multiple python threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm importing multiple python threads from different directories and then want to run them simultaneously.

Here's my parent:

```
import sys
import thread

sys.path.append('/python/loanrates/test')

import test2

thread.start_new_thread(test2.main())
```

and here's one of my child's:

```
import json 

def main():

    data = 'ello world'

    print data 

    with open( 'D:/python/loanrates/test/it_worked.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: start_new_thread expected at least 2 arguments, got 1
```

What is a simple way I can get this thread started (and then sequentially run multiple threads using the same method)

Comment: David if my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it

Answer (score 1):

You also need to provide a tuple with the argument to run the function with. If you have none, pass an empty tuple.

```
thread.start_new_thread(test2.main, ())
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.start_new_thread) of `thread.start_new_thread(function, args[, kwargs])` (boldface mine):

> Start a new thread and return its identifier. The thread executes the function *function* with the **argument list args (which must be a tuple)**. The optional kwargs argument specifies a dictionary of keyword arguments. When the function returns, the thread silently exits. When the function terminates with an unhandled exception, a stack trace is printed and then the thread exits (but other threads continue to run).

You can also:

```
thread = Thread(target = test2.main, args, kwargs)
```

`thread.`[`start()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start) `// starts the thread`

`thread.`[`join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) `// wait`

Read more on this approach to creating and working with threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905965/creating-threads-in-python).

Comment: I get invalid syntax from using this: `thread.start_new_thread(test2.main, ( , ) )`

Comment: Also using `thread = Thread(target = test2.main, args, kwargs)` i get Thread is not defined

Comment: "Thread is not defined" -> import the library (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873479/python-nameerror-global-name-thread-is-not-defined). I am checking regarding the syntax error now

Comment: Check it now (removed the comma `,` )

Comment: Thanks, however Is still get this error `Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr`

Comment: The exception happens when the main thread (the one that starts other threads) finishes. In your code the main thread quits before any of your sub threads (created by start_new_thread) finish. The solution is to wait at your main thread till the child threads ends. This answer demonstrates how to use threads well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9532410/2204926

Comment: Hm sorry I don't understand, how do i 'wait' ?

Comment: Using `join` :) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967093/how-to-wait-for-a-spawned-thread-to-finish-in-python)